# Twitch Authentication stuck on loading after entering auth app/sms code

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, twitch, twitch-api

I'm writing an app in C# (UWP) and I'm trying to authenticate Twitch user to get access token. I have this code:

```cs
using Windows.UI.WindowManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Open new window
    AppWindow TwitchAuthWindow = await AppWindow.TryCreateAsync();
    TwitchAuthWindow.Title = "Twitch Authentication";

    WebView TwitchAuthWebView = new WebView();
    TwitchAuthWebView.Navigate(new Uri($"https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize?client_id={ClientID}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl.OriginalString}&response_type=token&scope={string.Join(" ", Scopes)}"));
    ElementCompositionPreview.SetAppWindowContent(TwitchAuthWindow, TwitchAuthWebView);

    TwitchAuthWindow.TryShowAsync();

    TwitchAuthWebView.NavigationStarting += async (s, a)
    {
        // Do things if a.Uri.Host == RedirectUri.Host
    }
}
```

I manage to pass the first stage, i.e. entering username and password, without problems. Then on next page I enter code from Google Authenticator app (same with SMS code) and click "Submit" button, loading circle appears on the button and stuck on it.

When I close the window and open it again, the authorization page appears immediately and after clicking "Authorize" button everything work perfectly fine (redirection to RedirectUrl with access token).

I would like to add that the authorization in an external browser (Microsoft Edge) works without any problems.

I will appreciate any help and suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried to use the new [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winui2) in your app instead of using the old native WebView control?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the WebView2, as mentioned by @RoyLi-MSFT in the comment. Now authorization page works fine, but because I had to use 2.8.0-prelease version of Microsoft.UI.Xaml to get WebView2 in UWP, WebView2 itself has a lot of bugs, like flickering and problems with text fields and windows overlapping, so it's not the best solution until it is fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You could submit the feedback about Webview2 in the [WebView2Feedback](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues). The WebView2 team is handling feedback there.